# How does chrome://webrtc-internal compute keyFramesDecoded?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, webrtc, video-streaming, codec

I have been analyzing the JSON file generated using `chrome://webrtc-internal`, while running webrtc on 2 PCS.

I looked at [Stats API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/) to verify how webrtc-internal computes the keyframe rate.

By looking at Stats API/ [RTC Remote Inbound RTP Video Stream](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcinboundrtpstreamstats), it contains `keyFramesDecoded` which represents the total number of key frames, such as key frames in VP8, given that I set the codec to VP8.

keyFramesDecoded values are very small, i.e., 2 for a couple of minutes, and similarly for 3 and ...

My question is: How does the graph here make sense for `keyFramesDecoded`?
[image: graph here]

Answer (score 2):

That looks right to me.

Chrome is configured to send a keyframe every [3000](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/webrtc/api/video_codecs/video_encoder.cc;l=30?q=keyFrameInterval&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:third_party%2Fwebrtc%2F&start=11) frames. That means for 30fps you will see a keyframe every 100 seconds. The framesDecoded is being construct by lots of delta frames.

If you are in a unconstrained network and not dealing with lots of change in your video I would expect to see graphs like yours.

Comment: How does it compensate for the new objects that have entered the scene?
According to my understanding, the motion vector won't be able to extract them!

Moreover, it was configured to a constrained network using tc and netem tool, and the video has changing schene in small time interval < 1s.